# Gaussian Fit function anomaly

Tags: python, machine-learning, scipy, curve-fitting, gaussian

I have written a code to fit the gaussian function in a dataset by scipy curve_fit. There are a few different datasets. One with 19 points and one with 21 points and both of them include different datasets in range of 0.5-0.7, 1.0-1.2 and 1.5-1.7.
Surprisingly, when I ran the code in 19 point datasets, all three of them executed successfully but in case of 21 point datasets, only 1.5-1.7 ranged data had the right fit. All others were given with horribly wrong fit.
Here is the code.

```
#function declaration
def gauss(x, amp, mu, sigma):
    y = amp*np.exp(-(x-mu)**2/(2*sigma**2))
    return y

#fitting
popt, pcov = curve_fit(f = gauss, xdata = x, ydata = y)
#print(popt)
amp = popt[0]
mu = popt[1]
sigma = popt[2]
print(amp,mu,sigma)

#krypton value
krypton_y = amp/((math.exp(1))**2)
#print(krypton_y)
krypton_x1 = mu + math.sqrt((-2*(sigma**2))*math.log(krypton_y/amp))
krypton_x2 = mu - math.sqrt((-2*(sigma**2))*math.log(krypton_y/amp))
print(krypton_x1-krypton_x2)

#print(gauss([krypton_x1, krypton_x2], popt[0], popt[1], popt[2]))


#horizontal line
horizontal_x = np.arange(min(x)-0.01, max(x)+0.02, 0.01)
horizontal_y = np.repeat(0, len(horizontal_x))


#build fit set
x_test = np.arange(min(x), max(x), 0.0000001)
y_test = gauss(x_test, popt[0], popt[1], popt[2])
y_krypton = []
for i in horizontal_x:
    y_krypton.append(krypton_y)


#Vertical lines
vertical_y = np.arange(-20, amp+20, 0.01)
l = len(vertical_y)
vertical_mean = np.repeat(mu, l)


#fit data
fig = plt.figure()
fig = plt.scatter(x,y, label ='original data', color = 'red', marker = 'x')
fig = plt.plot(x_test, y_test, label = 'Gaussian fit curve')
fig = plt.plot(horizontal_x, y_krypton, color = '#830000', linewidth = 1) 
fig = plt.plot(vertical_mean, vertical_y, color = '#0011ed')
fig = plt.xlabel('Distance in mm')
fig = plt.ylabel('Current in nA')
fig = plt.title('Intensity Profile for '+gas+' laser | Z = '+str(z)+'cm')
fig = plt.scatter(mu, amp, s = 25, color = '#0011ed')
fig = plt.scatter(krypton_x1, krypton_y, s = 25,  color = '#830000')
fig = plt.scatter(krypton_x2, krypton_y, s = 25,  color = '#830000')
plt.annotate('('+"{:.4f}".format(mu)+','+"{:.4f}".format(amp)+')', (mu, amp), xytext = (mu+0.002,amp+0.5))
plt.annotate('('+"{:.4f}".format(krypton_x1)+','+"{:.4f}".format(krypton_y)+')', (krypton_x1, krypton_y), xytext = (krypton_x1+0.002,krypton_y+0.5))
plt.annotate('('+"{:.4f}".format(krypton_x2)+','+"{:.4f}".format(krypton_y)+')', (krypton_x2, krypton_y), xytext = (krypton_x2+0.002,krypton_y+0.5))
plt.legend()
plt.margins(0)
plt.show()
```

I am also adding two images, the correct fit and the wrong fit.
[image: Right fit in range 1.5-1.7]
[image: Wrong fit in range 1.0-1.2]

Comment: It isn't clear from the picture, but is that true, that original 21 points data contains points very far from the expected center? Can you just print the 21 points, or plot them alone without the fitted curve? So my guess is that there is an outliner point.

Comment: can you add code to generate the 3 datasets?

Comment: No sir, as it is a very small dataset, it's clearly visible that there is no outliner point.
1 0,
1.01 0,
1.02 0,
1.03 0,
1.04 0,
1.05 0.043,
1.06 1.88,
1.07 16.059,
1.08 60.125,
1.09 132.756,
1.1 143.096,
1.11 79.476,
1.12 25.415,
1.13 3.626,
1.14 0.558,
1.15 0.001,
1.16 0,
1.17 0,
1.18 0,
1.19 0,
1.2 0,

Comment: Yes, sure I can but sir, this is a code to fit curve in a given data. Why should we generate dataset from this?

Comment: the typical guess is probably a good one. Three things: start values, start values and finally start values.

Comment: In the data they are 10 points (x,0). The numerical calculus involves the logaritm of y which is infinite at those points. This makes it fail. The points with $y=0$ have no signifiance. You should eliminate them from the data and proceed for the numerical calculus with only the 11 remaining points.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make clear the difficulty we will use an elementary regression method.

[image]

We see that the fitting involves ln(y) which is infinite at the points k<6 and k>16. Those points cannot be used for the numerical calculus. Also the point k=16 is not reliable because the small value of y=0.001 is not accurate enough (only one sigificative digit). So, we use only the points from k=6 to k=15 in the next calculus.

[image]

[image]

This shows that the non-significative points have to be eliminated. Of course more sophisticated methods implemented in nonlinear regression package with iterative calculus gives better fitting according to some particular criteria of fitting specified in the software.